# All finite Baire measures are Closed-regular?

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis, measure-theory

Given a finite Baire measure $\mu$ on a topological space $X$, is it true that $\mu$ is closed-regular?

Where closed regular means that,

$$\mu(A) = \sup\{\mu(K)| K \space \text{is a } Z\text{-set}, K\subseteq A\}
= \inf\{\mu(K)| K \space \text{is a } U\text{-set}, A\subseteq K\}$$

I believe I have come up with a proof for this, but every similar stated theorem asks for $X$ to be a compact Hausdorff space. What's going on?

Comment: What are Z-sets and U-sets?

Comment: Sorry. A $Z$-set $K$ is of the form, $K = \{x\in X | f(x) = 0 \}$ for some $f\in C_b(X)$. A set is a $U$-set iff it is the compliment of a $Z$-set.

Comment: Also, if you leave the context of compact Hausdorff spaces, you have to define carefully what you mean by the Baire sets of $X$.  What is your definition?

Comment: The smallest $\sigma$-algebra making all the bounded continous functionals on $X$ measurable.